# When does a user's edit count decrease?

Tags: support, edits, users-page

In the users page we can see [top by edits](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all). For example, recently Nicolas Chabanovsky had 20,001 edits.

But right now only 20,000.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

When and why edits count could be decreased?

Comment: Related: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9963/15479.

Comment: This is just a guess, but perhaps this may be due to a roll-back of an edit made by this person.

Comment: @JohnOmielan no, rollback is just another edit. Not sure it is adding to the count since it's on the same post, but sure it's not a reason to decrease the number.

Answer (score 17):

The total edits count seen publicly does not take into account edits made on deleted posts.

So when a post is deleted, anyone who edited it will get a -1 in the count of edits.